# Leaflet Heatmap Dynamic data layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, php, heat-map

I am trying to add heatmap layer to my map. I have tried the following plugin:

http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html

From this plugin the data came from heatMapData.js. If I put the static data in heatMapData.js like following my heat map is working.

```
var testData={
  max: 500,
  data:[
    {lat:23.6681520914, lon:90.0811805, value:0.3},
    {lat:23.9010258772, lon:90.2883834839, value:0.9},
    {lat:23.7930778593, lon:90.423535, value:0.7},
    {lat:24.0279042498, lon:90.371648, value:0.5},
    {lat:24.1049427335, lon:90.2680428995, value:0.8}
  ]
};
```

For this I am using the following code in my index page:

```
$(function() {
    var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/ad132e106cd246ec961bbdfbe0228fe8/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }
    );

    var heatmapLayer = L.TileLayer.heatMap({
        // radius could be absolute or relative
        // absolute: radius in meters, relative: radius in pixels
        //radius: { value: 15000, absolute: true },
        radius: { value: 20, absolute: false },
        opacity: 0.8,
        gradient: {
            0.15: "rgb(0,0,255)",
            0.35: "rgb(0,255,255)",
            0.65: "rgb(0,255,0)",
            0.95: "yellow",
            1.0: "rgb(255,0,0)"
        }
    });

    heatmapLayer.setData(testData.data);

    var map = new L.Map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(23.7588, 90.38967),
        zoom: 7,
        layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
    });

    // make accessible for debugging
    layer = heatmapLayer;
});
```

Now I want to add data from my database. I have written a heatMapData.php which gives me following data as JSON format:

```
[{lat:23.6681520914, lon:90.0811805, value:0.3},
{lat:23.9010258772, lon:90.2883834839, value:0.9},
{lat:23.7930778593, lon:90.423535, value:0.7},
{lat:24.0279042498, lon:90.371648, value:0.5},
{lat:24.1049427335, lon:90.2680428995, value:0.8}]
```

What should I do to implement dynamic data layer that comes from heatMapData.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load dynamically (with ajax) your PHP file and set the content into `testData` var, as in your previous script. Then execute your original script without any changes.

Note that you will use $.ajax() jquery method to be able to set  `'async': false` option.

```
var testData = (function () {
var testData = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'pat/to/your/heatMapData.php',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        testData = data;
    }
});
return testData;
})();
```

Be sure your PHP file return the wanted values and a well-formated json file. It can be [tested online](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please edit your code? I think there is typo.

Comment: Its returning following error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: If you want any serious help, please post your code online : http://jsfiddle.net/